# Topology Euclidean Spaces

Tags: general-topology

I'm just wondering if it's true to assume to following:

Let $X$ be a space that's locally $m$-euclidean.

If $X$ is compact Hausdorff then it's an $m$-manifold, which implies that it's also metrizable.

But is it also Hausdorff because it's metrizable?

Comment: What exactly is your question? It's true that metrizable implies Hausdorff, but this is a very simple fact... are you asking if locally Euclidean implies metrizable? This is not true.

Comment: Aw, I entertained the possibility that Hausdorgg referred to some new separation axiom.

Comment: Metrizable means that you can find a metric $d$ which induces the given topology. And metric spaces are Hausdorff. Is that your question?

Answer (score 1):

It’s not entirely clear what you’re asking.

- A locally $m$-Euclidean space need not be Hausdorff: see the [line with two origins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Hausdorff_manifold#Line_with_two_origins).
- On the other hand, any metrizable space, whether locally $m$-Euclidean or not, is Hausdorff.